# Перевод строки в читабельный вид

Tags: python, кодировка, email, перекодировка

Подскажите как перевести данную строку в читабельный вид:

```
=?windows-1251?Q?=EC=E5=ED=F2=2Etxt?=
```

Оригинал строки

```
мент.txt
```

Comment: Этот формат называется "Quoted-printable", сам я питоном не силён, но вот что гуглится по словам Quoted-printable python:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249288/change-quoted-printable-encoding-to-utf-8 возможно вам подойдёт quopri.decodestring

Comment: @AK Рекомендую написать ответ. Ответ по ссылке-то на английском

Comment: @tutankhamun Мне такие ответы модераторы удаляют: ссылки на ответ на английском so нельзя считать за полноценный ответ и это в общем-то правильно. Поскольку я не парюсь по поводу величины кармы -- то ответ может написать кто угодно. Я сам писать не буду: питон не мой основной язык программирования. Я предлагаю самому топикстартеру подумать и написать свой ответ: и мозг потренирует, и копейку кармы принесёт.

Comment: @AK Так я и не имел ввиду - в ответ вставить ссылку и все. Написать по-русски то, что написано по-английски по ссылке. Может еще что-то от себя. Но это дело ваше

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python - email header decoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715870/4279)

Answer (score 5):

Вам поможет модуль [email.header](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html)

```
import email.header
a = "=?windows-1251?Q?=EC=E5=ED=F2=2Etxt?="
print email.header.decode_header(a)
```

Приведеная вами строка закодирована согласно [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). То есть формат строки такой:

```
=?кодировка?признак типа кодирования?закодированная строка?=
```

Признаков типа кодирования известно два `Q` и `B`. Соответственно они означают кодирование QuotedPrintable и Base64 соответственно.

`decode_header()` принимает строку в формате RFC2047, распознает тип кодирования, декодирует и возвращает два параметра - декодированная строка и кодировка.

Comment: Чтобы текст получить, нужно ещё `decode()` вызвать: `[(data, encoding)] = decode_header('=?windows-1251?Q?=EC=E5=ED=F2=2Etxt?='); print(data.decode(encoding))`

Comment: если в строке больше одной части, например строка из rfc 2047: `s = '=?US-ASCII?Q?Keith_Moore?= <moore@cs.utk.edu>'`,  тогда удобно `email.header.make_header()` использовать: `h = make_header(decode_header(s))`. И чтобы текст получить: `text = unicode(h)` или на Питоне 3: `text = str(h)` (можно напрямую печатать `print(h)`).

Answer (score 4):

```
import quopri

a = '=EC=E5=ED=F2=2E'
b = quopri.decodestring(a)
print(b.decode('windows-1251'))
```