# Получить Subject, From, To и вложения из письма

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap

Пробую работать с `imap` на Python. Подскажите, как правильно извлечь из письма тему, адрес отправителя, адрес получателя (или получателей) и вложения.

Делаю так (без вложений):

```
data = mail.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[1][0][1].strip())

subject = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
msg_from  = email.header.decode_header(msg['From'])[0]
msg_to  = email.utils.getaddresses(msg.get_all('to', []))
msg_date  = email.header.decode_header(msg['Date'])[0]

s = subject[0]
subject = s.decode("utf-8")                         # тема
msg_from = email.utils.parseaddr(msg_from[0])[1]    # отправитель

msg_to_addresses = '';
for i, (name, addr) in enumerate(msg_to):
    msg_to_addresses = msg_to_addresses + addr + ';'
msg_to_addresses = msg_to_addresses[:-1]            # получатель(и)

date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
if date_tuple:
    local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))

msg_date = local_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # дата

msg_uid = str(msg_id).replace("b", "")
msg_uid = msg_uid.replace("\'", "")                 # message uid
```

Всё работает, но периодически выскакивают ошибки (116 строка - это `subject = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]`):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 116, in
>
> subject = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]   File "C:\python\lib\email\header.py", line 80, in decode_header
> if not ecre.search(header): TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Или вот такая (123 строка - это `subject = s.decode("utf-8") # тема`):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 123, in
>
> subject = subject.decode("utf-8") # тема AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Подскажите, что и как поправить/добавить, чтобы работало стабильно + сохранялись вложения?

Comment: попробуйте [минимальный] пример ввода, который к ошибке ведёт привести. `print(ascii(msg['Subject']))`. `print(ascii(subject))`. См. [eщё комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542392/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4/542399#comment687700_542399)

Comment: jfs, вот вывод  '=?utf-8?B?0JjQl9Cc0JXQndCV0J3QmNCVINGB0YLQvtC40LzQvtGB0YLQuCDQvdCwINGB0LDQudGC0LUg0L3QsNC/?=\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?0YDQsNCy0LvQtdC90LjQtSDQkNGN0YDQvtC/0L7RgNGCINCS0L3Rg9C60L7QstC+LdCi0YDQvtC40YY=?=\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?0LogKNCc0L7RgdC60L7QstGB0LrQsNGPINC+0LHQu9Cw0YHRgtGMKQ==?='

Comment: всё работает (как в комментарии по ссылке показано): `str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(s)))` Какая ошибка у вас с этим кодом возникает?