# Python помогите с кодировкой imap

Tags: python, кодировка, imap

Принимаю письма с imap.
Неведомая кодировка. Помогите сделать что-то

```
 msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
 subject = msg['subject']
 # subject = base64.b64decode(subject).decode("UTF-8") #НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ
 print subject
```

Ответы:

```
 =?utf-8?b?0KHQvtCx0LXRgNC40YLQtSDQstGB0Y4g0L/QvtGH0YLRgyDQsiDRjdGC0L4=?=

 =?utf-8?b?0YIg0Y/RidC40Lo=?=

 =?utf-8?b?0JrQsNC6INGH0LjRgtCw0YLRjCDQv9C+0YfRgtGDINGBINC80L7QsdC40Ls=?=

 =?utf-8?b?0YzQvdC+0LPQvg==?=

 =?utf-8?B?0JrQvtC0INC/0L7QtNGC0LLQtdGA0LbQtNC10L3QuNGPINCw?=
```

Что надо сделать в коде, чтобы были русские буквы?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Перевод строки в читабельный вид](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542392/23044) Попробуйте код из моих комментариев там. Если не ясно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с помощью связанного вопроса. Спасибо.

```
subject_decode_array = email.header.decode_header(subject_decode)[0]
subject = urllib.unquote(subject_decode_array[0]).decode(subject_decode_array[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас base64 (буква В после utf-8?).
Декодируйте эти строки по типу:

```
import base64
print(base64.b64decode(строка).decode("UTF-8"))
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: Важное дополнение - если в кодированной строке будет присутствовать лишний, не относящийся к base64 символ, то на выходе будет ошибка. Поэтому совет всем, кто столкнется с подобной проблемой - проверяйте на сайтах-декодерах то, что вы пытаетесь декодировать! Возможно в вашей строке недекодируемый символ

Comment: да, у меня UnicodeDecodeError из-за некодируемого символа. Что делать с этим?

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что я правильно разбил ту строку по разделителю.

Код:

```
from base64 import b64decode

items = [
    ' =?utf-8?b?0KHQvtCx0LXRgNC40YLQtSDQstGB0Y4g0L/QvtGH0YLRgyDQsiDRjdGC0L4=?=',
    ' =?utf-8?b?0YIg0Y/RidC40Lo=?=',
    ' =?utf-8?b?0JrQsNC6INGH0LjRgtCw0YLRjCDQv9C+0YfRgtGDINGBINC80L7QsdC40Ls=?=',
    ' =?utf-8?b?0YzQvdC+0LPQvg==?=',
    ' =?utf-8?B?0JrQvtC0INC/0L7QtNGC0LLQtdGA0LbQtNC10L3QuNGPINCw?=',
]

for item in items:
    _, charset, _, text, _ = item.split('?', maxsplit=4)
    print(b64decode(text).decode(charset))
```

Консоль:

```
Соберите всю почту в это
т ящик
Как читать почту с мобил
ьного
Код подтверждения а
```